# How to get resultsState of react-instantsearch correctly with server-side render and integration with redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering, react-instantsearch

I try to get resultsState by call react-instantsearch's `findResultsState` API, But can't integrate with the component already connected with redux store. Error will show like below.

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of component . Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to component

Call api like this

```
findResultsState(
  component: Search, {
  searchState
});
```

My component looks like this. It is composed with some HOCs, and some HOC will connect with redux store through `react-redux` connect function.

```
Search = compose(
  intlWrapper,
  withModal,
  withGlobalAlert,
  withMainLayout,
  injectIntl,
)(Search);
```

Server-side Provider will render like this

```
const appString = renderToString(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={ context }>
      <Main />
    </StaticRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

Client-side:

```
const store = configureStore(history, 
window.__APP_INITIAL_REDUX_STATE__);

// Render component
hydrate(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Main />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Main

```
<Switch>
  { routes.map( route => <Route key={ route.path } { ...route } />)}
</Switch>
```

routes

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/search',
    component: Search,
  },{
   ...
  }
  ...
];
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share the relevant parts of your code with us. Without that it will be just a guessing game.

Comment: Could you please also add the code where you render the `Search` component and the `Provider` component?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete information, I add the code. thx.

Comment: do you get the error in client or server?

Comment: I made a repo for reproduce this problem, if you want maybe you can clone it. I thought it will more clarity and also ask for maintainer help.
github issue:
https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/issues/1208
example repo:
https://github.com/Clarencef/react_instant_question